# jupyter notebook, docker image asking token

Tags: python, docker, jupyter

I have downloaded `jupyter/datascience-notebook`  and run that using `docker run -it --rm --name ds -p 9999:8888 jupyter/datascience-notebook`  , now the page at `http://127.0.0.1:8888/?token=a5e7ab0debe441254f2268da2e3f179585a63eb22897056f`  is asking for token. Not sure what to enter in it, need some help.

Comment: Have you tried to enter the token given in the address?

Comment: Are you running on linux or windows?

Comment: I tried to enter token given in address, but says invalid credentials. I am on Ubuntu20 host, in  which docker is running

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I remember when you run the

```
docker run -it --rm --name ds -p 9999:8888 jupyter/datascience-notebook
```

a new token is being generated (each time you run there's a new token) and printed to the command line. You need to copy this token at paste it into the URL:

```
http://127.0.0.1:8888/?token=<new_generated_token>
```

this is also documented [here](https://jupyter-docker-stacks.readthedocs.io/en/latest/).

**UPDATE**:

if you're running in a secure network (not public) and you want to skip the token, there's a [different way](https://jupyter-docker-stacks.readthedocs.io/en/latest/using/recipes.html#run-jupyter-notebook-lab-inside-an-already-secured-environment-i-e-with-no-token) to run:

```
docker run -it --rm --name ds -p 9999:8888 jupyter/datascience-notebook start.sh jupyter notebook --NotebookApp.token=''
```

Comment: thanks,   docker run -it --rm --name ds -p 9999:8888 jupyter/datascience-notebook start.sh jupyter notebook --NotebookApp.token=''   works